# How to invoke a method of a Windows Service from VBScript?

Tags: .net, vb.net, com, windows-services, vbscript

Let's say I have created a Windows Service exposing a method **`foo(param1 as string)`**

Is it possible to somehow invoke `foo("SomeAwesomeString")` from VBScript directly (i.e., without it having to launch an additional process)?

The use case is this: I am trying to write an 'extension' application for **hMailServer (hMS)**, but hMS can only invoke VBscript scripts when an event happened. I *can* have the VBscript launch an .exe every time the event happened, but the processing involve opening and closing a connection to a back-end database. So, every invocation is very expensive. I had been thinking that I can reduce the expense by having a Service to maintain the connection (i.e., opening it once and re-open it if the connection closed). Plus by implementing the processing as background worker threads will result in a non-blocking processing + less process-starting overhead.

---

### Update: How I did it

Whew. After ***lots*** of searching and experimentation, I think I found a way. I'll post it as an answer below. If anyone can give a better answer than mine, feel free to post. If it's indeed better, I'll unmark my answer and mark yours.

---

#### Minor update/erratum:

I forgot to tell you that the Windows Service is created using VB.Net 2010. Sorry.

---

### Final Update: I Give Up

After searching all over the Internet -- and experimenting without end -- I give up.

I decided to *not* expose the method, but use ***Named Pipes*** instead. Now the VBScript script just need to write to an FSO opened to the `//./pipe/PIPENAME`, and let the service figure out what the heck the VBScript wants.

Thanks anyways for your attempts to help, friends.

Comment: Services don't export methods. You need to use an IPC mechanism.

Comment: @David yeah. Finally figured that out *sigh*. Thanks for the reminder, though :)

Comment: If I'd seen your question first time round I could have helped you out. Sadly I tend to steer clear of anything to do with VB and with vbscript in the mix too that's enough to discourage most people!!!

Comment: @David indeed. I went through *hell* for this one. Service + VB.Net + VB*Script* ... I sincerely hope I won't soon see a similar problem again.. if at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might combine the two approaches.

Implement your service, as you suggest, to maintain the requisite connections.

Then you from VBScript, invoke a tiny .exe whose entire purpose is to communicate its command line parameter to the aforementioned service.

In fact, rather than having to create a different .exe for each api (e.g., "hms-foo.exe", "hms-bar.exe" or whatever), make the name of the api just another command line parameter.

Now, you might have one very simple .exe called, say, hmscom.exe, which VBScript could invoke with a command line like, "hmscom.exe foo SomeAweSomString".  Internally, hmscom.exe would do whatever is necessary to invoke the exported API, foo() with the parameter "SomeAweSomString".

Even better would be to implement the above functionality within a DLL instead of an .exe and use the standard rundll32.exe to invoke an entry point of the DLL with the command line arguments as parameters, said function then communicating with the service as described above for the .exe.

This would make it more difficult for a user to spuriously call your service by accidentally double clicking an .exe file since there won't be one.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. However, isn't repeated invocation of an .exe is also kind-of expensive? I.e., the seeking-loading-initializing stuffs?

Comment: However, your posting gave me the idea of finding a way to export the classes of the service as COM Interfaces, and use VBScript's `CreateObject` function. I'll experiment with that. I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes check out [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324) it is away to comminicate between the two programs.

Comment: How do I use WCF inside VBScript? (The wscript/cscript kind, *not* the ASP kind)

Comment: Ok I was thinkging VB not VB script. In that case WCF may not be in option

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's how I do it:

1. Mark the classes to be exposed with `<ComClass(), ProgId("ServiceName")>` attributes
2. Check the "*Make assembly COM-Visible*" checkbox in the project's Property > Application > Assembly Information
3. Make the Service Installer class
4. Publish
5. Use `InstallUtil.exe` to deploy. E.g.:

   ```
   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe <appname>.exe.deploy
   ```
6. Use `regasm` to publish the COM Interface. E.g.:

   ```
   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm <appname>.exe.deploy /codebase <progid>
   ```
7. Done!

Now I can invoke the Service using COM Interface, e.g.:

```
Dim objService
Set objService = CreateObject("ServiceName")

Dim rslt
rslt = objService.Foo("SomeAwesomeString")
```

Whew! So many hoops to jump through :-/

---

### Update: Failed

After some testing... I found out that the CreateObject-ed instance is *not* the same as the currently running service *sigh*.

I'll experiment more.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did the **exact same thing** you were trying to do - yep, a helper app for hMailServer to screen the recipients of an email and reject the mail if any recipients are not allowed. I've had a vbscript do the same thing, but roughly 1% of the mails go undelivered because the vbscript errors out with a "DSN not found" - the DSN being the link to the DB which has the rules. Since I couldn't fix this, I thought of a helper app that would be called from hmail's OnAcceptMessage event. I'd pass the sender ID and the recipients to my app and I'd get a ok or not ok message with an explanation.

The way I did it is to create a TCP server app which listens on a predefined port. A winsock object is created to talk to the server in the vbscript which passes the sender/receiver. Since the server is persistent, there's no repeated calling of an exe or opening/closing of DB connections.

Here are some good resources for doing this:
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?453366-How-to-send-a-simple-string-via-TCP

https://www.symantec.com/connect/downloads/protocolvbs-windows-vbscript-test-tcp-service-response

I hope I get a reply from the author, after all it's only been 7 years, 9 months since the question was posted :)